# INSERT no inserta - PHP y SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, php8

tengo un inconveniente y es que quiero insertar unos datos en mi tabla de sql server pero este no hace nada

comparto el código que hace la inserción, este script lo llamo mediante AJAX

```
<?php


include("../../conexion.php");

if( isset($_POST['titulo']) && isset($_POST['descripcion']) ){

  $id_usuario  = $_POST['id_usuario'];
  $titulo      = $_POST['titulo'];
  $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO sistema_encuestasv1.encuestas (id_usuario, titulo, descripcion, estado) 
        VALUES ('$id_usuario', '$titulo', '$descripcion', '0')";;

$resultado = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql);

echo'<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Agregado Exitosamente");
  window.location.href="index.php";
  </script>';

}

?>
```

y estas son las columnas de la tabla a la que esta insertando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código de la modal donde envió toda los campos

```
<?php 

  date_default_timezone_set("America/Lima");
  $date = new DateTime();

  $fecha_inicio = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  
 ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />       <!-- Esto funciona para que esta pagina recargue cada 5 segundos -->

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Favicon - FIS -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../imagenes/Logo-fis.png">

    <title>USUARIO-Encuestas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   
      history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
      window.onpopstate = function () {
        history.go(1);
      };
    </script>

</head>
<body>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Sistema de Encuestas</a>
     
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    

      <!--NAVBAR-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" style="color: #fff">
          
         <?php   
        session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['u_usuario']) && isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) {
          echo "Bienvenido " . $_SESSION['u_usuario'] . "\t";

          echo "<a href='../cerrar_sesion.php' class='btn btn-danger' style='margin-left: 10px'>Cerrar Sesión</a>";
        } else {
          header("Location: ../index.php");
        }

       ?>
         
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Content Section -->
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h3>SISTEMA DE ENCUESTAS</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <h4>Encuestas:</h4>
             <div class="table-responsive">
                <div id="tabla_encuestas"></div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Content Section -->


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/encuestas.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>

<!-- Modal Agregar Nueva Encuesta -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_agregar" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Nueva Pregunta</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="titulo" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Título Pregunta</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" placeholder="Título Pregunta" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Descripción</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="fecha_final" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Fecha Final</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fecha_final" value="<?php echo $fecha_inicio ?>"  autocomplete="off">
                  <p>Fomato: año-mes-día horas:minutos:segundos</p>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="agregarEncuesta()">Agregar Pregunta</button>
                <input type="hidden" id="hidden_id_usuario" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id_usuario'] ?>">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Modificar Producto -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_modificar" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modificar Producto</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="modificar_titulo" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Título</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modificar_titulo" placeholder="Título">
                        </div>
                    </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Descripción</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="modificar_descripcion" placeholder="Descripción"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="fecha_final" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Fecha Final</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modificar_fecha_final" placeholder="Fecha de Cierre" autocomplete="off"
                  value="<?php echo $fecha_inicio ?>">
                  <p>Fomato: año-mes-día horas:minutos:segundos</p>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="modificarDetallesEncuesta()">Modificar Encuesta</button>
                <input type="hidden" id="hidden_id_encuesta">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y también muestro el archivo **encuestas.js** que llama mediante AJAX al archivo **agregarEncuesta.php** del primer codigo de arriba

```
// Agregar nueva encuesta
function agregarEncuesta() {
    // Obtener los valores de los inputs
    var id_usuario  = $("#hidden_id_usuario").val();
    var titulo      = $("#titulo").val();
    var descripcion = $("#descripcion").val();
    var fecha_final = $("#fecha_final").val();
    // Agregar encuesta con el método ajax POST
    $.post("ajax_encuesta/agregarEncuesta.php",
        {
            titulo      : titulo,
            descripcion : descripcion,
            fecha_final : fecha_final,
            id_usuario  : id_usuario
        },
        function (data, status) {
            // Cerrar el modal
            $("#modal_agregar").modal("hide");
            // Mostrar las encuestas nuevamente
            mostrarEncuestas();
            // Limpiar campos del modal
            $("#titulo").val("");
            $("#descripcion").val("");
            $("#fecha_final").val("");
        }
    ) ;
}
```

simplemente no guarda nada, si logre hacer que elimine y edite, pero no guarda nada, alguien me ayuda porfavor

Comment: Ponle esto despues de la linea donde haces el sqlsrv_query:  `if( $resultado === false ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }` para poder ver si te da errores y cuales son

Comment: lo he colocado, sin embargo no hace absolutamente nada no genera ningún error ni nada

Comment: Pues una de dos, o bien no da error (con lo cual algo tendrias que ver en la tabla donde realizas el insert) o bien sí da error pero lo estas llamando con ajax de algun modo que no veo en tu pregunta y no se esta mostrando esa salida de error por eso

Comment: Si estas llamando a ese script por ajax, muéstralo en la pregunta, para ver como lo haces,  y de paso cambia eso que te he dicho antes por esto otro: `if( $resultado === false ) { file_put_contents("errores.txt", print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); die(); }` y luego lo vuelves a ejecutar y te vas a la carpeta donde esté el script y mira si te ha creado un archivo llamado **errores.txt** en ella y lo miras con un editor para ver si alli salen errores.  Tambien podria ser que no hiciera nada porque no superara este condicional: `if( isset($_POST['titulo']) && isset($_POST['descripcion']) ){`.

Comment: he editado la pregunta y he agregado como se manda a llamar con ajax,, también he cambiado lo que me dijiste y este es lo que me sale en el archivo **errores.txt** ```Array (    [0] => Array  ( [0] => 22018  [SQLSTATE] => 22018       [1] => 245
            [code] => 245
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'admin' to data type int.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'admin' to data type int.
        )
)```

Comment: Pues parece que el problema lo tienes al recuperar el valor de id_usuario, pues creo que te coge la palabra "admin" en lugar de un número, que es lo que espera después el INSERT, y de ahí ese error: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'admin' to data type int.` ... revisa lo que hace esto: `var id_usuario  = $("#hidden_id_usuario").val();` y el porque en ese input hay un valor de string que pone **admin** en lugar de un número

Comment: es que el campo id_usuario no es un numero, así se llama el campo del usuario como tal, cuando usaba mysql, en ese campo me insertaba 0 pero me dejaba insertar, revise y no encuentro la razon por la cual inserta admin

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136416/discussion-between-marco-tulio-and-masterguru).

Comment: Si en la tabla la columna `id_usuario` es numérica, debes asegurarte de que en `$_POST['id_usuario']` estás pasando un valor numérico, o bien, debes colocar a mano un valor numérico para esa columna, si hay algo que justifique hacer esto. SQL Server no es tan permisivo como MySQL y está bien que sea así. Quizá este fallo te esté diciendo que hay un mal diseño en tu BD. ¿Por qué habría que hacer un INSERT donde el valor de una columna no importa, o da igual lo que sea y si no coincide el tipo de datos que se inserte un `0`? Esto a la larga podría ser muy problemático.